# How can I break a long for loop down into smaller more readable pieces that still perform?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, scope, compare

In one of my projects I need to make a very long for loop that contains 9 different if/else statements. I'm trying to write cleaner, more maintainable, and readable code. I was hoping I could break this for loop down into a series of smaller functions.

I wasn't sure how to do this, so tried it and wrote a for loop in a function and a condition if else statement in another and tried calling it in the for loop. 
This did not produce the desired result as  i was undefined. 
I understand this is because of the scope. My question is, is there a way to break down a for loop like this?

Here is the code:

```
let x = 5;
let y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

const compare = () => {
  if (x == y[i]) {
    alert('hello');
  }
}
const loop = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    compare();
  }
}

loop();
```

Comment: Depends what all those `if/else` are doing. Your over simplified example doesn't tell us much about what your overall goal is

Comment: If the `if/else` are actually working this is probably better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ which focuses more on improving working code

Comment: You can *pass* the value of `i` as argument to the other function: `compare(i);` and `const compare = (i) => ......`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple pass 'i' as parameter to compare function,

```
let x = 5;
let y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const compare = (i) => {
 if (x == y[i]) {
  alert('hello');
   } 
}
const loop = () => {
 for (let i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
   compare(i);
 }
}

loop();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach instead.

```js
window.onload = () =>{
let x = 5;
let y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

const loop = ()=>{
    y.forEach(item => {if(item===x) alert('hello')})
     
    }    
loop();
}
```